# how to make user's profile link work in index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My question deals with User's `index.html.erb` whose code is posted at the bottom of this post. As you can see from the models, profiles `belongs_to` users.

I am trying to have a functional link of the user's profile in User's `index.html.erb`.

Obviously it's not working hence this question. The error I get is this: `ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Users#index

I know that `user_profile_path` is a functional path by itself. But since I'm inserting it in User's `index.html.erb` page instead of Profile's `index.html.erb` page, it's a little tricker than usual?

How do I make User's profile link work?

Thank you for your help.
`

**User**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :profiles
end
```

**Profiles**

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**Profiles Controller**

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_profile, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /profiles
  # GET /profiles.json
  def index
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @profiles = @user.profiles
  end

  # GET /profiles/1
  # GET /profiles/1.json
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @profile = @user.profiles.find(params[:id])

     respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
    end
  end

  # GET /profiles/new
  def new
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @profile = @user.profiles.build
  end

  # GET /profiles/1/edit
  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @profile = @user.profiles.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /profiles
  # POST /profiles.json
  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @profile = @user.profiles.new(profile_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.save
        format.html { redirect_to @profile.user, notice: 'Profile was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @profile }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /profiles/1
  # PATCH/PUT /profiles/1.json
  def update

    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @profile = @user.profiles.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.update(profile_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @profile, notice: 'Profile was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @profile }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /profiles/1
  # DELETE /profiles/1.json
  def destroy

    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @post = @user.profiles.find(params[:id])

    @profile.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to profiles_url, notice: 'Profile was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

    def set_user 
      @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    end
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_profile
      @profile = @user.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def profile_params
      params.require(:profile).permit(:user_name, :user_id)
    end
end
```

**User Profile**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email)
    end
end
```

**Routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    root to: 'users#index'

  resources :users do 
    resources :profiles
  end
end
```

**User's index.html.erb**

```
<h1>Users</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>User Profile</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= user.first_name %></td>
        <td><%= user.last_name %></td>
        <td><%= user.email %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'User Profile', user_profile_path(user) %>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', user %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(user) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New User', new_user_path %>
```

**EDIT**

**Rake Routes**

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                 Controller#Action
             root GET    /                                           users#index
    user_profiles GET    /users/:user_id/profiles(.:format)          profiles#index
                  POST   /users/:user_id/profiles(.:format)          profiles#create
 new_user_profile GET    /users/:user_id/profiles/new(.:format)      profiles#new
edit_user_profile GET    /users/:user_id/profiles/:id/edit(.:format) profiles#edit
     user_profile GET    /users/:user_id/profiles/:id(.:format)      profiles#show
                  PATCH  /users/:user_id/profiles/:id(.:format)      profiles#update
                  PUT    /users/:user_id/profiles/:id(.:format)      profiles#update
                  DELETE /users/:user_id/profiles/:id(.:format)      profiles#destroy
            users GET    /users(.:format)                            users#index
                  POST   /users(.:format)                            users#create
         new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                        users#new
        edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                   users#edit
             user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                        users#show
                  PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                        users#update
                  PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                        users#update
                  DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                        users#destroy
```

**EDIT TWO in reference to a couple of answers beneath**

[image]

Comment: show your rake routes

Comment: @BrenoPerucchi, done

Comment: You didn't has any association with this ID user. if you execute this rails console `User.find_by(id:x).profiles` this will probably return `nil`

Comment: Are you sure about this User association with profiles? One User `has many` profiles? if you sure then you have to create profiles some point. Should be created on create a `user` or now in this page `index users` you should to use the `action` `create` instead `show`

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of your route

`user_profile GET    /users/:user_id/profiles/:id(.:format)      profiles#show`

You need to pass the user id and the profile id to the path.
Something like the following:

`<td><%= link_to 'User Profile', user_profile_path(user.id, user.profiles.first.id) %>`

Since the relation on the user model is a `has_many` you will need to specify which profile to link to (I used the first as an example). Or you could link to all of the profiles using `user_profiles_path`

Comment: when I tried your answer, this is what I got ... please look at the screenshot in question above ...

Comment: also, I'm curious what it means to do `user.id` and `user.profiles.first.id` ... why do you have to specify it so explicitly? isn't user object sufficient? asking because i'm not used to seeing that and wondering how to kno when you're supposed to be so specific

Comment: The screenshot is a different issue. Basically `@user` isn't set anywhere when you call `find` on it. You would also need to find the profile based on your code, so it would be `@user.profiles.find`, or `Profile.find`. Using the objects is fine as the params for the url helper

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter where you use the helpers. But since user `has_many` profiles, you need `user_profiles_path(user)` here.

Answer (score 0):

```
user_profile GET    /users/:user_id/profiles/:id(.:format)      profiles#show
```

Or you do this. Because you need pass a profile ID on action show

```
<td><%= link_to 'User Profile', user_profile_path(user, user.profiles.first) %>
```

or you have to change to index page.

```
<td><%= link_to 'User Profile', user_profiles_path(user) %>
```

Because your relation with profiles is to_many and you have to identify the action show which profile your are editting.

Maybe your relation with profile should be has_one. Like One User has One Profile

Comment: please look at the screenshot in the post above ... when I tried your first answer, that is what I got ... second answer worked fyi ...

Answer (score 0):

Since a User has many Profiles, you can't have a path to a single user profile without specifying which profile. The path helper to a single user-profile would need an instance to the user and a specific user-profile instance.  Without knowing whether you want to show all the profiles for a User or just one, I suggest running `rake routes` and looking at the results to find the helper name for which ever one you need.

Based on your routes, if you want to use `user_profile_path`, I think this would be the correct call:

```
user_profile_path(user, profile) # profile must be a valid instance of Profile, eg. `user.profiles.first`
```

If you want a link to all profiles for the User, this should be the correct call:

```
user_profiles_path(user)
```

but, then you'd want to check for the :user_id parameter in ProfilesController#index and only show the profiles for that User.

Example:

```
if params[:user_id].present?
  user = User.find(params[:user_id))
  @profiles = user.profiles
else
  @profiles = Profile.all
end
```

Comment: your second path worked ... your first path got me this error: `NameError in Users#index `

Comment: also ... I'm curious about the example code you put in your answer ... that's supposed to go in profile's controller index? .....

Comment: Yes, that is supposed to go in ProfilesController#index.  Answer updated.  For the first path, did you assign `profile`?  You could use `users.profiles.first`, instead, but it has to exist.  I think you should tell us which path you want working, and why a user would have more than one profile.